# Convert C Code To .net (C# Or VB.net)

Tags: c++, c, vb.net

I Need Convert This Code To .net (C# or VB.net)
Please Help Me For Do This:I Need Convert This Code To .net (C# or VB.net)

Please Help Me For Do This:

```
word CalCRCCCITT(word val,byte data8)
{
byte tmp,i;
word CRC;
tmp = (val>>8)^data8;
CRC = 0;
for (i=8;i;i--)
{
if (0x8000&CRC)
{
CRC <<= 1;
CRC ^= 0x1021;
}
else
{
CRC <<= 1;
}
if (tmp&0x80)
CRC ^= 0x1021;
tmp <<= 1;
}
val <<= 8;
val ^= CRC;
return val;
}
word CalDemo(byte *tb_Bufp,byte tb_Len)
{
word tw_Val;
byte i;
tw_Val=0xffff;
for (i=0;i<tb_Len;i++)
{
tw_Val=CalCRCCCITT(tw_Val,(*tb_Bufp++) );
}
return tw_Val;
}
```

Comment: You should probably have at least made some effort to convert it yourself, even if you didn't get very far

Comment: for C# you don't need much changes at all, you could just do what the compile errors tell you to do (add some casts to byte, compare a couple of things to zero, add `unsafe`, replace `word` with `ushort`) and it'll work. It wouldn't be nice, but it'll work. So why not try that first?

Comment: Sure, fetch me a cup of coffee and we'll talk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCITT has standard CRC algorithms, so I bet there's someone who has this code ready for you. A quick search on the net gave me the following articles:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/marcelcrcencoding.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csRedundancyChckAlgorithm.aspx

You'll find more if you [search for "C# ccitt crc"](http://www.google.com/#q=C#+ccitt+crc)

Comment: Thanks For answer but this is Specific if you can translate this code please help me thanks